# Priority semaphore in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a  multiple threads program, each thread calculates the GCD of two numbers and print out the result. The problem I have right now is I have to print the result in ascending order. I'm not sure how to do this. This is school assignment. we are not allowed to use any extra thread to sort the result and output and cannot do the print out in the main thread too.

Comment: In ascending order of what? The GCD, I suppose?

Comment: Yes. small int to large int

Comment: Care to explain me something? In a comment you say "we are not allowed to use any extra thread" and yet you added the "multithreading" tag? What is going on exactly?

Comment: Perhaps he means in addition to some set number of threads being used in a template given to him by a professor?

Comment: Easiest solution would be to push all results into, say, an ArrayList, and then call sort() on it. If there's threads, protect the pushing with a synchronization lock.

Comment: @BlackVegetable good point, but then I'd like to see that template. Otherwise it's `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` and there ya go.

Comment: I have to create one thread per two numbers(find the gcd and output). The numbers are from the txt file. so the thread numbers depends on the txt file. I cannot create any extra thread beside the threads that calculate the gcd.

Comment: By not being able to call print from the main method, he couldn't throw the results into an ArrayList, sort them, and print out the result once the other threads are complete, could he?  Drat.

Comment: @BlackVegetable exactly... This exercise does not make sense. You must collect _all_ results before you can print out anything. And the teacher is asking yet again to reinvent the wheel, Java has already all the necessary builtins to achieve that.

Comment: @fge Would it be possible to have each thread wait while signaling which values it will print once it is finished waiting? Then you could have them unlocked by a main thread in a certain order and they'd print in their own methods...

Comment: By specifying a priority for the threads that are being created he can suggest to the JVM the order of execution, but he won't have deterministic results, if I remember correctly.  So that won't work despite the title of this question.

Comment: @John back to more practical matters, what Java threading _primitives_ are you allowed to call?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you talking about. what is Java threading primitives?

Comment: @John `Thread`, `Runnable`, `Callable`, `FutureTask`, `ThreadPool`, etc etc -- Java has so many of them, so do you have any restrictions or none at all?

Comment: @John see my answer, I have done a toy implementation... But since the details are unclear as to what you are allowed to use, I took some (as low-level) liberties (as I could).

Comment: Thanks, We don't have limitation for the Java threading primitives.

Answer (score 5):

I understand that you need to print the GCDs in ascending order.

If that is the case, you can simply spawn as many threads as you need and have them put the result in a shared collection, then print the collection from one of those threads once all the other spawned threads have finished.

For example, have the first thread start the other threads, then join and print. Or you could use a CountDownLatch to know when the collection is full.

Make sure the collection is either thread safe or protected by a lock.

Comment: He stated that he cannot print from the main thread, nor spawn additional threads beyond a teacher-provided limit.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Edited - in that case he can use one of the threads as a printer. As you mentioned, he needs to calculate all the results first anyway so the printing has to be done after all threads have done their computation.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the results ordered, one fact is obvious: you cannot do this until you have collected *all* the results.

What is more, some couple of numbers may return the same GCD (9 and 3, 18 and 3)...

Since it is unclear what you are allowed to use, here is a sample implementation using Java's `FutureTask` (and `Callable`, we have to)

Note, no exception checking or anything, therefore unsuitable for any production purposes... It even obeys the constraint that "cannot do the print out in the main thread too".

```
public final class GCDExcercise
{
    /*
     * Method returning a Callable<Integer>. The .call() implementation returns
     * the GCD of the two numbers given as arguments. Left to implementers.
     *
     * n1 and n2 MUST be declared final, as they are used from an anonymous
     * class returned from that function.
     */
    private static Callable<Integer> gdc(final int n1, final int n2)
    {
        return new Callable<Integer>()
        {
            @Override
            public Integer call()
            {
                // Calculate gdc of n1 and n2 here, return it
            }
        };
    }

    /*
     * One worker. The only thing it does is delegate calculation to the task
     * above, we let FutureTask handle the rest (and there is a lot).
     */
    private static class GCDComputation
        extends FutureTask<Integer>
    {
        GCDComputation(int n1, int n2)
        {
            super(gdc(n1, n2));
        }
    }

    /*
     * IMPLEMENTATION SPECIFIC. Here, Guava's ImmutableList is used to return a
     * very small subset of values. In "real life", will return something from
     * a file or something else. Left as an exercise to the reader.
     */
    private static Collection<GCDComputation> getComputations()
    {
        // Shuffle, add, etc -- results will be consistent anyway
        return ImmutableList.of(
            new GCDComputation(18, 17), // 1
            new GCDComputation(12, 3),  // 3
            new GCDComputation(9, 180), // 9
            new GCDComputation(8921830, 989280), // 10
            new GCDComputation(8723, 982) // 1
        );
    }

    // Main program, with obligatory throws
    public static void main(String... args)
        throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException
    {
        // Our list of threads
        List<GCDComputation> threads = new ArrayList<GCDComputation>();

        /*
         * Add each FutureTask to the list -- and run it. We MUST do so, since
         * those are not daemon threads.
         */
        for (GCDComputation result: getComputations()) {
            threads.add(result);
            result.run();
        }

        /*
         * Collect the list of result: create the list, add elements to it, and
         * sort it.
         */
        final List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (final GCDComputation result: threads)
            ret.add(result.get());

        Collections.sort(ret);

        /*
         * Print results! In a separate thread since this is what is asked...
         */
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                for (int i : ret)
                    System.out.println(i);

            }
        }.run();

        // Outta here 
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,We don't have limitation for the Java threading primitives

Answer (score 1):

Calculates the GCD and then sleep the thread by GCD secs

Comment: Actually, that's kind of a clever solution to this problem.  (If poor programming practice in general, it seems to me like it would work. +1)

Comment: nice, but the numbers can be up to 2048bit

Answer (score 0):

By the title of your question, if not its wording, it sounds like you need to use a counting semaphore. You could do something clever using each thread's GCD value as its countdown value. Details left as an exercise for the reader :-)